# Read init_stack task_struct from /dev/kmem

Tags: linux-kernel

I am root on an x86 64 bits Linux Kernel.

My goal is to understand task_struct structure.

I have looked at init_task address in /proc/kallsyms

I found: 0xffffffff83613740

I wanted to read this task_struct entry from /dev/kmem with this c code. (This code is runned as root user):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fd = fopen("/dev/kmem","r");
    fseek(fd,SEEK_SET, 0xffffffff83613740);
    unsigned char buffer[1];
    fread(buffer,1,1,fd);
    fclose(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see i read just a single byte, not the whole task_struct object.
I get a segfault when running this code as root.

Can you tell me what is wrong ?

/proc/kallsyms init_task does not gives us the kernel address of init's task_struct ?
If so how can i get the address ?

Thanks